# convertir imagen base64 a file en angular 9

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy usando https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper para recortar imagenes subidas desde angular a mi api en node, el problema es que las transforma a base64 y aunque esta todo bien, no puedo subirlas asi al servidor asi que estoy tratando de convertirlas a tipo File

```
let nuevo = new FormData();

let split = this.croppedImage.split(",")[1];
let blob = new Blob([atob(split)], { type: "image/png" });
let file = new File([blob], "imageFileName.png");

nuevo.append("tipo", "perfil");
nuevo.append("user", this.id.toString());
nuevo.append("image", file);

this.dataService.nuevaImage(nuevo).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  err => console.log(err)
)
```

hasta el momento de usar el split esta todo ok, pero al transformarla a File y enviarla a la api se ve negro y en local dice que el formato no es compatible. 
PD: La api no arroja error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pude solucionarla con 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-image-croppe-anartz?fbclid=IwAR2caX0Kd1IkZ9e_2vBlUm9hTXCUCb5BZtlezwAtwEMl_YcKaaFj472bVGE

es un poco engorroso el tema del decodificado pero esto me sirvio